# React Native MapView Expo does not work on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a problem with Maps on Android with Expo on React Native, but on IOS everything is allright!!! Can someone help with this

Comment: You need to add way more detail to your question. There's nothing anyone can do to help you with what you've posted. What errors are you getting, what does your code/project look like, what version of Expo are you using, what are you testing on (simulator/device/OS versions), what have you tried to fix this so far, etc? Please put more effort into your question before posting.

Comment: Please post your code so that it is to easy to help you

Answer (score 0):

import React from 'react';
                        import {
                            AppRegistry,
                            Text,
                            View,
                            StyleSheet,
                            Image,
                            Alert,
                            Button,
                            TouchableHighlight,
                            AsyncStorage,
                          } from 'react-native';

```
                    import Router from '../main';

                    import Expo from 'expo';
                    import FontAwesome, { Icons } from 'react-native-fontawesome';

                      import {
                        createRouter,
                        NavigationProvider,
                        StackNavigation,
                      } from '@expo/ex-navigation';

                    import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
                    import WebView from 'react-native-maps';
                    var Item = require('./languages/dictionary.json');

                    export default class Maps extends React.Component {
                        static route = {

                          navigationBar: {
                          title: function(params) {
                              if (typeof params.language === 'undefined') {
                                return '';
                              }
                              return Item[params.language].maps;
                            }
                          }
                        }

                    constructor(props) {
                        super(props);

                        this.state = {
                          data:[{
                            id:"",
                            name:"",
                            address:"",
                            lat:"",
                            lng:""
                          }],

                        settings:[{
                            ImageFolder:"",
                            TimeToUpdate:""
                          }],    

                          language:0,
                          latitude: null,
                          longitude: null,
                          latitudeDelta:0.0000467769713,
                          longitudeDelta:0.0421,
                          error: null,
                          //version:null,

                        };
                      }


                    componentDidMount() {

                        AsyncStorage.getItem("version").then((value)=>{
                          this.setState({"version":value})

                        }).done();

                        AsyncStorage.getItem("radius").then((value)=>{
                          this.setState({"radius":value})

                        }).done();

                        AsyncStorage.getItem("language").then((value)=>{
                          this.setState({"language":value})

                        }).done();

                        AsyncStorage.getItem("language").then((value)=>{
                          //this.setState({"language":value})
                          this.setState({language: value})
                          //console.warn(this.state.language)
                          this.props.navigator.updateCurrentRouteParams({language: value});
                        }).done();

                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                          (position) => {
                            this.setState({
                              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                              latitudeDelta:0.0000467769713,
                              longitudeDelta:0.0421,
                              error: null,
                            });


                          //Alert.alert("https://api.parkingwatcher.com/"+this.state.version+"/parkings.php?lat="+this.state.latitude+"&lng="+this.state.longitude+"&radius="+this.state.radius)
                          fetch("https://api.parkingwatcher.com/"+this.state.version+"/parkings.php?lat="+this.state.latitude+"&lng="+this.state.longitude+"&radius="+this.state.radius)
                          .then((response) => response.json())
                          .then((responseData) => {        
                            this.setState({data: responseData});

                          })
                          .done();

                          fetch("https://api.parkingwatcher.com/"+this.state.version+"/settings.php")
                          .then((response) => response.json())
                          .then((responseData) => {        
                            this.setState({settings: responseData});

                          })
                          .done();



                          },
                          (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
                          { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
                        );


                      }

                    onPressAddFavourites(){
                      Alert.alert(
                      'Alert Title',
                      'My Alert Msg'
                    )
                    }


                      render() {
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.container}>
                            <MapView style={styles.map}
                                    showsScale
                                    showsPointsOfInterest                
                                    region={{
                                      latitude: parseFloat(this.state.latitude),
                                      longitude: parseFloat(this.state.longitude),
                                      latitudeDelta: parseFloat(this.state.latitudeDelta),
                                      longitudeDelta:parseFloat(this.state.longitudeDelta),
                                    }}   
                                >

                                {this.state.data.map(marker => {
                                  return(
                                    <MapView.Marker coordinate={{
                                        latitude: parseFloat(marker.lat),
                                        longitude: parseFloat(marker.lng), 
                                        }}
                                        >
                                      <MapView.Callout>
                                        <View>
                                          {/*<Image source={{uri: 'https://data.parkingwatcher.com/parkings/'+marker.id+'.jpg'}} style={{height: 200, width: 200}} />*/}
                                          <Image source={{uri: this.state.settings.ImageFolder + marker.id+'.jpg'}} style={{height: 200, width: 200}} />
                                          <Text style={styles.name}>{marker.name}</Text>
                                          <Text style={styles.address}>{marker.address} {this.state.language}</Text>

                                          {/*<Text>{this.state.radius} </Text>*/}
                                          {/*<Text>{this.state.settings.ImageFolder} </Text>*/}
                                              <Button
                                                onPress={this.onPressAddFavourites}
                                                title="Add to Favourites"
                                                color="#841584"
                                                accessibilityLabel="Add to Favourites"
                                              />
                                        </View>
                                      </MapView.Callout>
                                  </MapView.Marker>
                                  )
                                })}

                            </MapView>  

                        </View>


                        );
                      }
                    }

                    var styles = StyleSheet.create({

                      container: {
                        flex: 1,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
                      },
                        map: {
                          position: 'absolute',
                          top: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          bottom: 0,
                        },
                        name:{
                          textAlign : 'center',
                        },
                        address:{
                          textAlign : 'center',
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: i have no errors. On IOS everything is allright, but when I open maps in Android it just close my application